# Confusing LOD expressions in Tableau

Tags: formula, tableau-api, level-of-detail

I have the following data structure:

```
Scope,Metric ID,Item ID,System,Color
TRUE,A1,123,A,Red
FALSE,A1,123,B,Red
FALSE,B1,234,C,Red
TRUE,B1,234,A,Red
FALSE,B1,415,A,Red
```

I'd like to group by Scope, filter on TRUE and get the unique list of Items, then count these Items and subtract from a total unique count for the `Color = Red`.

So, in the example above, I have 3 unique items for `Color = Red` and I have 2 unique items with `Scope = TRUE`, so the result should say `3 - 2 = 1`.

Because of the data structure, simple filtering won't help. I realize I need to use a complex LOD syntax, but after having tried them for a few hours, I find them rather confusing.

Does anyone have an idea how to write an LOD expression to give me the desired count? Thanks!

Comment: For `color = RED` and `scope = TRUE` there are 2 distinct system. Why do you need 1 ? Can you rephrase your question ?

Comment: could you please provide the desired output? I mean, do you need just 1 as result or do you need also a sheet with dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using 3 calculated fields like this:
then doing a count distinct on them.

1:

```
if [Color]='Red' then [Item ID] end
```

2:

```
if [Scope]='TRUE' then [Item ID]        end
```

3 :

```
subtract the 2 calculated fields i,e 2-1
```

It gives out 1.